# How to display unread message view in chat list screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing a chat application and where I need to display unread message view for newly coming unread messages. Is there any solution to do implement that solution.

Comment: You can add a particular color for the newly unread message and the other color for the read message(To recyclerView individual cell). Just an idea which some apps do. Or you can simply show the count of the unread message similar to WhatsApp.

Comment: Please post some code. If something is wring, happy to help you :)